# Risks of using custom DNS instead of my VPN DNS

Tags: vpn, dns

If I use a custom DNS like NextDNS instead of my VPN service's DNS (NordVPN), where DNS queries go through the tunnel, will there be a privacy risk or some major disadvantages?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you are using a VPN for "privacy" reasons, then it would make sense to tunnel all the traffic including DNS queries through that VPN. Why not do that ?

Comment: Because NextDNS is much more customizable + analytics.. So public DoH is not good for privacy?

Comment: Commercial VPNs do not protect your privacy. Commercial VPNs take your private internet traffic and move the privacy impact from your ISP to the commercial entity that operates the VPN. The overall level of access to your private traffic is identical, you're just moving the traffic away from an (often well-regulated) ISP to an unregulated business.

Comment: I think VPNs with good reputations + no logs + audits have much more trust than ISPs :) At least for me..  And they are same commercial like ISP.. They selling some product but not user data..

Comment: @Wan Are you sure they do not sell user data? How would you know? Do you have public reports of trustworthy third party auditing companies that detail the inner configuration of their services? Did you audit this VPN provider yourself? Do you trust the provider not to employ rogue employees that would sell user data on the black market or to work for intelligence agencies? How does the provider prevents such things to happen? How did you verify that those mechanisms are indeed in place and effective? On the other hand, do you have proof that your ISP sells user data?

Comment: Most of the time, VPN services advertised on youtube are snake oil or just overpriced proxies changing your IP to bypass geographical restrictions.

Comment: So what can people do? Do you have better reasonable alternative how to encrypt traffic?

Comment: @Wan There is nothing you can do. Unless you operate your own ISP, you have to trust *someone* else. The point is that VPNs and ISPs are the same level of trustworthiness. Unless you personally audited either of them, you have to trust that they don't violate your privacy.

Comment: "So what can people do? Do you have better reasonable alternative how to encrypt traffic?". Rent a server somewhere you trust, install a VPN server on it, just for you, and encrypt traffic between you and it. Of course you "loose" some features for which you do commercial VPNs like multiple geographical locations, redundancies, etc. but you control all pieces. There is some burden. But also, in a world where all should be HTTPS or soon, and even DNS can run over HTTPS/TLS, most of things are encrypted already. What else do you have?

Comment: See also: https://www.nytimes.com/2021/10/06/technology/personaltech/are-vpns-worth-it.html "Many virtual private network services that were meant to protect your web browsing can no longer be trusted. Here are other ways."

Answer (score 2):

Any perceived benefit you achieve by using a VPN shouldn't be affected by what DNS server you choose, except some may do more privacy-harming things with your data than others. Maybe there will be more latency. Unless you have specific concerns not mentioned in the question, the only true exception to your privacy would be if you somehow chose a DNS server that is locally routable, in which case that traffic would not go through the VPN and you'd have a "DNS leak".

That said, as discussed in the comments, you are simply trusting your data with another company that could be more or less shady than your ISP.